# Thumbnail & Category link aside post

Tags: posts, customization

I've been trying to figure out for days how http://quotelicious.com was able to place thumbnails and category links in a separate box alongside the actual post.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

They are actually doing this is one loop, here's an example to show similar structure.

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <div class="article">

        <div class="left">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail( $size, $attr ); ?>
            <?php get_the_category(); ?>
        </div><!-- end left side -->

        <div class="right">
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        </div> <!-- end right side-->

    </div>

<?php endwhile; else: endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thank you much! It worked! The only change I made was putting  <?php the_category(', ') ?>  instead of  <?php get_the_category(); ?>

Comment: Thats great, btw you can further read [WP loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) Document for more info about this. :)

Answer (score -2):

Wordpress themes such as MH News does this by default for all archive pages. Check this [quotes website](http://www.braintrainingtools.org/skills/category/quotes/time-quotes/) for reference

Comment: Please post a real solution, not just a link to a possible solution where someone might or might not find a solution